# What is a term for someone who doesn't know what they haven't experienced?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, synonyms, pejorative-language

I'm struggling to find a word or short term for a person or group of people who do not experience jealousy/remorse/etc. due to a lack of something. For example, people from the middle ages could not be upset about the lack of cell phones because cell phones did not exist back then and they had no idea something along those lines could exist.

It doesn't have to be the lack of a tangible thing either, the term I am looking for could represent the lack of anything. Another example would be how many young children do not understand the concept of racism. Since they have never been exposed to bigotry or prejudicial behaviour, they do not harbor negative feelings towards people who are different than them simply because they are different.

My first thoughts were *naive* and *ignorant*, but those words tend to carry a negative connotation with them. It sounds unfair to call a person from the middle ages ignorant because they didn't have a cell phone or to refer to a baby as naive for not being a racist. Is there a better term out there?

Comment: .......innocent

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You should work that into an answer – I think it's the perfect word.

Comment: I feel like innocent has the inverse connotation of naive. Granted, describing the baby in my example as innocent would be very accurate, but people of the middle ages are not necessarily "innocent." By definition, innocent is great, but by interpretation, I think it's a little off.

Comment: This question is tagged as American English, but in British English there's a phrase that, I think, captures the essence of what you want:  ["They don't know they're born."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81496/origin-of-they-dont-know-theyre-born)

Comment: I'd call someone not knowing of cell phones "happy"...

Comment: Actually "ignorant" is a pretty good fit.  One of my professors used to describe certain people as "ignorant," quickly clarifying that it wasn't an insult, it was a [literal interpretation of the definition sans connotation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignorant).

Comment: Ignorance is bliss.

Comment: @JackRyan I agree that the literal interpretation of ignorant is a good fit. My concern is that in clarifying my intent with the use of ignorant, I lose the conciseness of the word. A sort of "robbing Peter to pay Paul" type scenario.

Comment: @DrydenLong Agreed.  A real dilemma.

Comment: @Jack Ryan: I suspect your professor wouldn't have used the term 'ignorant' face-to-face when addressing people lacking certain aspects of knowledge. He might not have had time to clarify which particular polyseme was intended. Situation and especially audience are controlling factors in choice of words (or should be).

Comment: @DrydenLong  it's quite a philosophical question if you ponder on it. You claimed that children wouldn't know about racism if they hadn't first been exposed to it. I would like to disagree with you there. They would not know the terminology, but the fear/dislike/distrust of someone physically different, an outsider, or just a foreign person is what I might call a primal instinct. It is something which we are born with, it helped our survival as a species. It is modern-day society, and its accepted social customs which have dictated that we need to or ought to co-habit with our neighbours.

Comment: Go to any mixed school playground and you will see children are capable of being mean to each other. Sometimes, it is enough just to have large ears to be a victim of bullying. Children after the age of three are no longer "innocent" or "*unblemished*" beings.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You may want to use *oblivious*.

Comment: this word connotes forgetfulness rather than innocence I think.

Comment: @user49727 I disagree that *oblivious* connotes forgetfulness. To me it's inattentiveness and lack of awareness, thus fitting the question nicely.

Comment: I have read "oblivious" used in this type of context several times. Depending on the context, it can be perfect.

Comment: I like this too. The big selling point for me is that it doesn't imply an *intent* to not know. The only downside I see is that oblivious is often used to describe a lack of knowledge of something that is currently happening. For the baby example, this works perfect. For the middle ages people, it may imply that cell phones existed, they just didn't know about them. I'm sure I could work around that implication though. Something along the lines of "People of the middle ages were oblivious to the fact that cell phones would one day exist." Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want negative connotations, perhaps simply describe them as [**unaware**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unaware):

> not aware or conscious; unconscious: *to be unaware of any change*.

Other possibilities include *uninformed* or *incognizant*.

Answer (score 10):

I posted a comment rather than an answer earlier, because there are usually off-flavours when a word is shoehorned into a particular desired meaning. As OP keeps pointing out. 'Naive', I feel, does have a negative ('should know better') connotation (though the denotation need not carry that sense). 'Ignorant', though basically meaning 'not cognisant of some facts', does carry a strong connotation of 'barbaric'.

However, *I'd* use the term 'innocent' here - I think most people would rapidly discount the 'not guilty in the eyes of the law' sense - because a lot of the senses it carries (see reference below) overlap pretty well with OP's requirements. (In the words of a friend, 'All words are infinitely polysemous' - so you'll never find the perfect fit, with no possibility of undesired connotations - and we won't all totally agree on what those connotations are.)

**in·no·cent**  (adj.)

1. Uncorrupted by evil, malice, or wrongdoing; sinless: an innocent child.

2.
a. Not guilty of a specific crime or offense; legally blameless: was innocent of all charges.
b. Within, allowed by, or sanctioned by the law; lawful.

3.
a. Not dangerous or harmful; innocuous: an innocent prank.
b. Candid; straightforward: a child's innocent stare.

4.
a. Not experienced or worldly; naive.
b. Betraying or suggesting no deception or guile; artless.

5.
a. Not exposed to or familiar with something specified; ignorant: American tourists wholly innocent of French.
b. Unaware: She remained innocent of the complications she had caused.

6=6. Lacking, deprived, or devoid of something: a novel innocent of literary merit. [AHD]

Answer (score 6):

***tabula rasa***

***blank slate***

(for the present context) the OED defines this term as follows:

an absence of preconceived ideas or predetermined goals; a clean slate:

*the team did not have complete freedom and a tabula rasa from which to work*

> a mind not yet affected by experiences, impressions, etc.
>
> a young mind not yet affected by experience
>
> the mind in its hypothetical primary blank or empty state before receiving outside impressions
>
> something existing in its original pristine state
>
> *cultural definition* Something new, fresh, unmarked, or uninfluenced. Tabula rasa is Latin for “blank slate.”

Thus you could say: My mate is new to this corporate world of jealousy and hostility - he's a *tabula rasa*.

> Example sentences from Collin's dictionary:

"But you don't start with a tabula rasa (clean slate), you have to deal with society as it is, and try to make constructive progress.
TIMES, SUNDAY TIMES (2001)

It was on this tabula rasa , Picasso believed, that a new art form could originate.
TIMES, SUNDAY TIMES (2002)

Porn, on the other hand, is a tabula rasa as far as greatness is concerned.
Victoria Coren, Charlie Skelton ONCE MORE, WITH FEELING: HOW WE TRIED TO MAKE THE GREATEST PORN FILM EVER (2002)

With someone new, you're a tabula rasa , which has its charms for those who enjoy reinventing themselves.
GLOBE AND MAIL (2003)

Comment: I like this a lot, my only concern is that it may end up requiring a good deal of explanation (or definition) to the general public. +1 though, and I think I may be able to do something with the term "blank slate."

Comment: thanks - I've added the exact translation, which can be used in its own right.

Comment: I think this really pushes the term into a usage that forces it to do a job it wasn't meant to do. _Tabula rasa_ is specifically meant to indicate a completely blank slate, a mind which is entirely unformed. It is not supposed to apply merely to some portion of a mind or some aspect of a person's experience. To say that a person is a _tabula rasa_ is to say that they have lost all mental information, or have not yet begun to store any. I would certainly not accept it as applying to something as highly specific as not having knowledge of cell phones.

Comment: This is not my invention. Please see example sentences in Collin's dictionary online.

Comment: If you understand the term, every one of those usages refers to the correct use of the term, not the one you are thinking. Without going into detail, each one refers to a COMPLETE blank slate, not a portion of anything.

Comment: The specific quality of art and Picasso? Porn and the specific quality of greatness? You don't seriously think that the last example refers to a completely unformed mind? Please refer to this link for further information on its current usage: http://www.ehow.com/about_5064181_definition-tabula-rasa.html   Like it or not magazines and video games have adopted this term :)

Comment: @John M. Landsberg - oh and here's another example from the web: My little brother is new to the world of rock music. He’s a total blank slate, so I intend to show him all the coolest bands and make sure he has good taste.

Comment: Moreover, these words both imply a readiness to absorb or learn something new.  The context of the OP is focusing on the effects or comparison (externally) from the *absence*

Answer (score 5):

Since all your examples refer to the lack of a *negative* experience which can be considered positive (well, not entirely, there a negative experiences you cannot avoid forever, e.g. death), translations of the German word [unverdorben](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=unverdorben) might fit quite well:

- pristine
- unspoiled / unspoilt
- ingenuous (or innocent, as [Edward Ashworth suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125524/what-is-a-term-for-someone-who-doesnt-know-what-they-havent-experienced#comment258936_125524))
- untainted
- uninjured

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest *uninitiated* and *unindoctrinated*, as well as, in certain specific contexts, such as when you want to suggest that someone has not been damaged, misguided, or warped by the awareness of or adverse teachings of a prejudicial stance like racism, *unspoiled* or *untainted*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **[uncomprehending](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/uncomprehending)**

> Not understanding; having little or no comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, sweet oblivion and the bliss of ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

The term I use to define this is "The uninitiated"

Comment: +1, but please add a definition to your answer and possibly a source such as Wiktionary, m-w.com or the like.

Answer (score 2):

Another apt word that applies is ***terra incognita***.

> an unexplored or unknown land, region, or area for study
>
> unknown territory :  an unexplored country or field of knowledge

Answer (score 2):

In the situation described by the OP, I'd be inclined to use the adjectival expressions *nescient* [of X], *unexposed* [to X], or *unfamiliar* [with X].

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I've posted my thoughts on the thread you linked to.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

- *blissfully anaware*

An example: The small neck hugging collar and gathered shoulders
   create the perfect illusion of a dainty torso, and when tucked into a
   pair of high-waisted shorts a universally flattering silhouette is
   achieved. For the breastily gifted or those with none such gifts. For
   the    brawny broad-shouldered lass or for one with no shoulders. For
   the young and fashion-forward and the **blissfully unaware** elderly
   alike.

Slightly off-topic: there is an expression that could be used to describe how the (bad) things such people are anaware of affect them:

- *like water off a duck's back*

Answer (score 1):

**Uncontaminated**

Obviously you would have to use this term in a metaphorical sense. But the concept that one could live one's life untouched or contaminated by the need to possess worldly possessions, or be so pure in heart as to not know nor understand what evil is, is I believe, not a new one. I have not studied philosophy; I have not studied anthropology nor the science of human behaviour, but I have witnessed life, and for a time I used to believe in religion and wanted to follow its teachings and be "pure" and "free" of *materialistic* things. And then I realized I was living in the real world, and not one based on wishful thinking and dreams.

<sub>It's also called growing older and wiser.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As Edwin Ashworth posted in the comments: *innocent*.

Answer (score -1):

The idiom 'green behind the ears' come to mind.

Comment: You mean "wet behind the ears," but in any case, that merely means "immature," and wouldn't work here.

Comment: Maybe not John, but i still meant "green". Slight attitude difference between "green" and "wet". Wet necessarily means immature, while "green" has stronger undertones of not having yet reached a point of graduation. https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/wordroutes/green-behind-the-ears/

Comment: The [vocabulary.com article](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/wordroutes/green-behind-the-ears/) supports John's point:  “green behind the ears” is not actually an idiom, it's an *idiom blend* (two idioms mixed up together) or a  *[fractured idiom](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070628055351AA8mp5V)* (a humorous distortion of a real idiom)